# I want 1st field to be not equal to 2nd field (both fields are foreign key to same model)

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to raise validation error when my 'reference' field is same as 'contact', but
`def clean` won't work.

Here is my code:

```
class FacultyRegistration(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Faculty Role")
    contact = models.OneToOneField('Contacts.Contact', related_name='faculty_Contact', unique=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference = models.ForeignKey('Contacts.Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='faculty_reference',)
    # I tried def clean but it wont work
    def clean(self):
        if self.contact == self.reference:
            raise ValidationError('Primary and secondary inclinations should be different.')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.contact} ({self.role})"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Faculty Management"
        verbose_name_plural = "Faculty Managements"
```

Comment: No issue in this code snippet sofar. Are all migrations up to date? What can you see for these two variables when you set a breakpoint at `if self.contact == self.reference:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a form in forms.py :

```
class FacultyRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FacultyRegistration
        fields = '__all__'

    def _post_clean(self):
       contact = self.cleaned_data.get('contact')
       reference = self.cleaned_data.get('reference')
       if contact == reference :
          self.add_error("reference", "Primary and secondary inclinations should be different.")
```

In django/forms/forms.py you can see that _post_clean is an internal hook for performing additionnal cleaning after form cleaning is complete.

You will read in the source code :
full_clean method run:

```
self._clean_fields()
self._clean_form()
self._post_clean()
```

clean method is a hook for doing any extra form wide cleaning after field.clean(). Post clean method is running after form clean.